# TestNG @BeforeGroups method is not executing

Tags: java, testng

I have the following code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeGroups;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {

    @BeforeTest
    private void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("BeforeTest!");
    }

    @BeforeGroups(groups = "demo")
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("BeforeGroups!");
    }

    @Test(groups = { "demo" })
    private void test() {
        System.out.println("Test!");
    }
}
```

When I run the class, only "BeforeTest!" and "Test!" are being printed in the console. Does anybody know why the `@BeforeGroups` method is not called?

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
BeforeTest!
Test!
PASSED: test

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. try to `clean` before `test`

Comment: Still not working. What version of TestNG are you using? I'm using 7.4.0

Comment: I'm using 7.6.0

Comment: And you're running it directly from the class? Or do you have an .xml file? Because when I try to run it from .xml file, it works for me too.

Comment: Both ways: from IDE and from maven command line

Comment: That's strange. I found this post where it says that @BeforeGroups should only work when running the .xml file:

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2319

Comment: TestNG always creates `testng.xml` under the hood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249448/discussion-between-robert-ilin-and-alexey-r).